# Learning web scraping.. need some clarity on xpath="/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div/table[5] using xpath plugin

Tags: r, web-scraping, xpath, rvest

I am learning web scraping in r , and understand the HTML code.. but there is slightly some confusion here...

CODE 1 :

```
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population"
ten_most_df <- read_html(url) 


ten_most_populous <- ten_most_df %>% 
  html_table() %>%
  .[[6]]
```

CODE 2 :

```
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population"
    ten_most_df <- read_html(url)




ten_most_populous <- ten_most_df %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath="/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div/table[5]") %>% html_table()
```

Are the methods use in code 1 and 2 the same as in code 1 , we are scraping the 6 node , however things are not clear to me Code 2 , as div[3] repeated twice. Can you please give some clarity on this. will be of great help.. thanks.

Comment: I'd also consider `html_node(xpath='//*[@id="10_most_populous_countries"]/parent::h3/following-sibling::table') %>%html_table` over both of them. It's a personal preference over whether indexing into tables versus relying on other existing relationships in html. Long selectors/xpaths should be avoided as prone to break. I would generally seek stable looking attributes/elements (based on experience). Possibly also consider using wayback machine to get a feel for changes in the html for this page (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]` means the 4th `div` child of the 3rd `div` child of the 3rd `div` child of the body element.

You really should be finding that out by reading a reference book on XPath, not by asking on StackOverflow.